# Finding a Basis for $L(V,W)$ where $ \dim V = n$, $ \dim W = m$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find a basis for $L(V,W)$ (the set of linear maps from $V$ to $W$)
where

$ \dim V = n$, $ \dim W = m$. Let $(v_1,...,v_n)$ be a basis for V and $(w_1,..,w_m)$ be a basis for W. I had the idea to take $m*n$ linear transformations such that for

$i \in {1,...,n}$,

$j,k \in {1,...,m}$

define $T_{ij}(x_k) = w_j$ if $k=i$ and $0$ if  $k \neq i$. Then I want to show that these are independent and spanning if my reasoning this far is correct. Hints appreciated.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct; this is a good basis to work with.  It helps to start by thinking in terms of matrices.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom please elaborate on this! My teacher was talking about that today in class and I was somewhat confused. Is $T_{ij}$ the matrix with 1 in the $ij$'th position and 0 elsewhere?

Comment: You can see $V$ as $k^n$, and $W$ as $k^n$ (if you are working with real numbers, $k=\mathbb{R}$), and for the basis you can choose the canonical one. Then the linear transformation $T_{ij}:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ that sends the vector $e_i$ to the vector $e_j$ is the matrix with zeroes except in the $i,j$-th position. Then, if they form a basis, what is the space $L(V,W)$ in that context?

Comment: @jamesdickens that's right.